# Bootstrap modal open on clicking image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

when i click `menu-5_1.png` the below model should pop up

```
        <li class="men_5l" ><a id = "pop" href="#"><span><img src="images/menu_5_1.PNG" alt=""></span> <p>Mp3</p></a></li>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Don't Wait, Login now!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;padding-right: 30px;">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#Login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Login">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">



                                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server" 
                                            Text="log in"  />


                                        <a href="javascript:;">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option>Mr.</option>
                                                    <option>Ms.</option>
                                                    <option>Mrs.</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPagingGoto" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" id="emailField" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Mobile</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" id="txtPhoneNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" id="p1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" id="pass1" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                       Re-Enter Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" id="pass2" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">  


                                       <asp:Button ID="Button2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server" Text="Register"/>    


                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                            Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OR" class="hidden-xs">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row text-center sign-with">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3 class="other-nw">
                                    Sign in with</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                   <div style="height:20px;width:100%;"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</a></div><div style="margin-top: 35px; width: 100%;"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        Google +</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pop").click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
        });
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Check in your browser console. Any error is there?

Comment: jquery plugin added?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("ul").on('click','#pop',function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed below reference libraries in your application.

https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#pop").click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/zz9wqroc/

Comment: its not work for me https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/o74zt4zy/, can you please explain it?

Comment: @Cola, Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/o74zt4zy/1/. Error because of http/https reference issue.