# Open Image on Click in Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, image, modal-dialog

Now, I know this has been asked plenty of times before, but every example I have found, I have tried but it does not work.

I have a list of imageURL's which get displayed on the webpage. I want to be able to click that image which then opens a modal up and displays the enlarged image.

The sources which I have been through thus far are:

[Modal Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304437/bootstrap-modal-open-on-clicking-image)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p57wx8r/)

But whatever I seem to try, it does not work and when the image is clicked it just directs me back to the home page via the `href="#"`.

The code I am using is as follows (This is an angular app)

- Loop over the images for a product and embed the url into the `src` tag:

  ```
    <a *ngFor ="let image of product.productImageList" href="#" id="pop">
     <img id="imageresource" src="{{image.imageUrl}}" style="width: 10%; height: 10%; margin-left: 10%;">
   </a>
  ```

Then create the HTML for the modal:

```
<!-- Creates the bootstrap modal where the image will appear -->
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image preview</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then finally, the javascript (For now it is embedded in the html via a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
$("#pop").on("click", function() {
 $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('src')); // here asign the image to the modal when the user click the enlarge link
 $('#imagemodal').modal('show'); // imagemodal is the id attribute assigned to the bootstrap modal, then i use the show function
});
</script>
```

I have no idea as to why this does not work. Any clues would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

use pop class rather than id in hyperlink  ()

```
 <script>
    $(".pop").on("click", function() {
     $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src')); 
     $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Does not work plus why would I use the class when i have used id in the html?

Comment: id is used when we have a unique element over the page but we have multiple anchor tag and multiple image,

Comment: Ok so do I need to change to:

<a *ngFor ="let image of product.productImageList" href="#" class="pop">

Comment: Still just directs me to #

Comment: You could just remove the href attribute if you're not using the anchor tags for navigation. Alternatively, you could pass the event object into your click handler and call event.preventDefault().

Comment: @AlexanderDunn, `$(".pop").on("click", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); 
     $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src')); 
     $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
    });`